# Regex to match multiple patterns

Tags: regex

I am trying to match below paterns:

```
A-Test!1.2
A-Test
ATest
A-Test!1.2.3
```

in below text:

```
 [A-Test!1.2]    [xyz]      [def]
 [A-Test]    [xyz]      [def]
 [ATest]    [xyz]      [def]
 [A-Test!1.2.3]    [xyz]      [def]
```

I tried my hand @ regex

> `[^\[]+(\-*\!\d.\d(?:.\d))`

But it is only matching one line:

[image]

Can you please guide on how to get the matches done for all lines?

Comment: `(?<=\[)[A-Z]-?[A-Za-z]+(?:!\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?(?=])`? See https://regex101.com/r/uMPVEp/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use `?` for optional pattern

I assume the difference between the `[]` boxes is the searched string must start with a capital letter, and the part from `!` onwards is optional. You can make something optional with a `?` behind it.

You can use this regular expression to find your example texts:

```regex
\[([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9-]+(![\d.]+)?)\]
```

See here to play around with it:
https://regex101.com/r/5ekTkJ/1

Answer (score 1):

You may spell out all the pattern parts, e.g. like

```php
(?<=\[)[A-Z]-?[A-Za-z]+(?:!\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?(?=])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uMPVEp/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=\[)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `[` char immediately on the left
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more letters
- `(?:!\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?` - an optional group matching

  - `!` - a `!` char
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` - one or more digits and then zero or more occurrences of `.` and one or more digits
- `(?=])` - a positive lookahead that requires a `]` char immediately on the right.